# Why is the script tag a red task?

Tags: javascript

```html
<script>
  console.log("script1:start");
  setTimeout(()=>{
    console.log("settimeout");
  },1000)
  new Promise((resolve)=>{
    console.log("script1:promise1");
    resolve()
  }).then(()=>{
    console.log("script1:then1");
  })
  console.log("script1:end");
</script>
<script>
  console.log("script2:start");
  new Promise((resolve)=>{
    console.log("script2:promise2");
    resolve()
  }).then(()=>{
    console.log("script2:then2");
  })
  console.log("script2:end");
</script>
```

After performing the micro task in the first script tag, why not the macro task distributed by settimeout, but the macro task of the next script tag?

Comment: Because, after the task of the first `<script>` is executed, and the promise microtask is executed, the macrotask of the `setTimeout` callback is not yet in the queue, and will not be there for at least another 1000ms or so. On the other hand, the macrotask of the second `<script>` tag is readily available.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I'm sorry, this is my first time, so if there's anything wrong, please forgive me.

Comment: I cannot reply to your comments because of the honor value of my poverty. Thank you for your answers.

Comment: So when does the callback in setTimeout enter the task queue?